# Set form & to date maximum duration for owl-date-time in angular8

Tags: datetimepicker, angular8

I am using a range slider of [Owl NG Datetime Picker](https://daniel-projects.firebaseapp.com/owlng/date-time-picker) ([Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-datetimepicker?file=src%2Fapp%2Frange%2Frange.component.html)).

In this range slider, I want to set range (max duration of both dates) between from date & to date should be 10 (any int value). In other words, if I select From date Jan 1, 2020 then I can only To date between Jan 1, 2020 to Jan 10, 2020.

Also, it would be helpful if I can get an event when from or to date getting selected.

As per the documentation right now only below 4 [events](https://daniel-projects.firebaseapp.com/owlng/date-time-picker#events-owl-date-time) are available for OWL-Date-Time
[image]

**Edit** - I need some event/behavior like beforePickerClosed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using the **dateSelected** owl-date-time event.
Following code solves the issue.

First you have to define following props:

```
@Input() min: Date | string = null;
@Input() max: Date | string = null;
@Input() minDaysRangeAllowed: number;
@Input() maxDaysRangeAllowed: number;
private minDatePreserved: Date | string;
private maxDatePreserved: Date | string;
private from: moment.Moment;
private to: moment.Moment;
```

Initialize the fallback min and max dates.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.minDatePreserved = this.min;
      this.maxDatePreserved = this.max;
}
```

Then this method handles the logic of setting the min and max dates for a selection:

```
limitDaysRangeSelection(date: moment.Moment) {
  if (!this.from && !this.to || (this.from && this.to) || (this.from && date.isBefore(this.from) && !this.to)) {
    this.from = date;
    const nextMaxDate = moment(this.from).add(this.maxDaysRangeAllowed - 1, 'day');
    const nextMinDate = moment(this.from).add(this.minDaysRangeAllowed - 1, 'day');
    this.min = nextMinDate.isAfter(moment(this.maxDatePreserved)) ? this.maxDatePreserved : nextMinDate.toISOString();
    this.max = nextMaxDate.isAfter(moment(this.maxDatePreserved)) ? this.maxDatePreserved : nextMaxDate.toISOString();
    this.to = null;
  } else if (this.from && !this.to && (date.isAfter(this.from) || date.isSame(this.from))) {
    this.min = this.minDatePreserved;
    this.max = this.maxDatePreserved;
    this.to = date;
  }
}
```

more on how it works [here](https://medium.com/@andriy.vl/how-to-limit-days-range-selection-with-owldatetime-date-picker-1da74d07e3f)